# Confusion regarding Halmos's proof of Schroder-Bernstein

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

In Halmos's proof of Schroder-Bernstein, he defines the parent of $x \in X$ as $f(x)$ and vice versa for an element of $Y$. So each $x \in X$ has an infinite sequence of descendants,
$$
x, f(x), g(f(x)), f(g(f(x))), \ldots
$$
and so on. He then partitions $X$ and $Y$ as follows. We let $X_X$ be the set of elements "born in $X$," i.e., the elements of $X - g(Y)$ and their descendants in $X$; $X_Y$ is the set of descendants in $X$ of the elements of $Y - f(X)$; and $X_{\infty}$ is the set of elements in $X$ for which the chain regresses forever.

I think I understand this construction. It makes sense why $X_X$ and $X_{\infty}$ are disjoint. I assume that $X_X$ and $X_Y$ and $X_Y$ and $X_{\infty}$ are disjoint because of injectivity of $f$ and $g$, but I'm not able to fully grasp this. So I'd appreciate some help on why exactly this is a partition.

Halmos then says "we partition $Y$ similarly." When he constructs the bijection, he argues that if $x \in X_X$, then $f(x) \in Y_X$. I'm not sure I fully understand this. Is $Y_X$, by definition, the set of descendants in $Y$ of the elements of $X - g(Y)$? If I'm understanding this correctly, $Y_X$ is the set of those descendants; $Y_Y$ is the set of elements of $Y - f(X)$ and their descendants in $Y$; and $Y_{\infty}$ is the set of elements in $Y$ whose ancestry regresses ad infinitum.

I'm also having some trouble understanding exactly why the restriction of $f$ to $X_X$ is a bijection. It's certainly injective since $x$ is injective. Why must it be surjective?

Answer (score 1):

I will first explain why $X_X$, $X_Y$, and $X_\infty$ are disjoint. If $x \in X$, then only 3 things can possibly happen. (1.) $x$ has an ancestor in $X$ with no parent. (2.) $x$ has an ancestor in $Y$ with no parent. (3.) $x$ has no parentless ancestor. You can see for yourself that $x$ can only satisfy exactly one of the three conditions. So, by defining $X_X$, $X_Y$, and $X_\infty$ in the way we did, these 3 sets are not only disjoint, they partition $X$. Specifically, each element of $X$ belongs to exactly one of either $X_X$, $X_Y$, or $X_\infty$.

In your second paragraph, your understanding that $Y_X$ is the set of descendants of elements of $X - g(Y)$ is correct.

To see that $f$ restricted to $X_X$ is a surjective, we see that $f(x)$ is an element of $Y$ which has $x$ as an ancestor, and $x$ has an ancestor terminating in $X$ since $x \in X_X$. This means $f(x) \in Y_X$. This tells us that the restriction of $f$ to $X_X$ maps $x$ into $Y_X$ and nowhere else. The map is surjective by the way we defined $Y_X$. $f$ restricted to $X_X$ is bijective.

If there's anything you'd like me to clarify, don't be afraid to comment.

Comment: This is very helpful. The only thing I'm having trouble seeing is why (1) and (2) are mutually exclusive. It makes sense why (1) and (3) and (2) and (3) can't simultaneously occur, but it seems at least plausible to me that $x$ could have an ancestor in both $X$ and $Y$ with no parent.

Comment: We can go into more detail about why $X_X \cap X_Y = \emptyset$. If $x \in X_X \cap X_Y$, then there would be two finite sequences such that $f(g(f(\cdots g(y)\cdots ))) = g(f(g(\cdots g(y)\cdots ))) = x$ for some $y \in Y$. Can you see how this leads to a contradiction?

Comment: I'm not able to see it. I think it must be because $f$ and $g$ are injective, but the sequences don't have to have the same size, so I can't just apply left cancellation to find a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry, I'm also not completely sure I understand why there exist such sequences. Could you explain?

Comment: @JohnT One sequence must be shorter than the other, so either $g(f(g(\cdots g(y)\cdots )))$ is a parent of $f(g(f(\cdots g(y')\cdots )))$ is a parent of the other, or vice versa by the injectivity of $f$ and $g$. If we are trying to assume that has two distinct parentless ancestors, then this is not possible since one of the ancestors will have to have the other as its parent.

Comment: How do we know these sequences exist, though?